# Can I put an underscore into a migration description?

Tags: flyway

Is there any way to put underscores into a migration description?

I want to be able to reference a table that has underscores in the name.

Let's say I have a table called `car_model` and I want the migration description to read "Add 2022 models to car_model".  Or, "Add smog_rating column to car_model".

Right now Flyway is turning any underscore into a space.

I tried creating a file `V7__test\_me.sql` and the description is `test\ me`.